# Power App load form not in Browser full screen

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I currently have a Power App form that opens a new item or new form in a new browser window. The issue is not with the new window but the fact that it is not to scale. I would like to have it open in a friendly view that the form was intended to look like. Any suggestions?

Comment: By default form opens in right side panel when you customize it using power apps. Did you change anything to open it in new window?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the list form via File > Settings > Screen size + orientation.

Switch Size from “Custom” to “Small” or “Large” and the list form should be in the auto resize mode.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#further-customize-your-form